# C# object array = null, doesn't free memory

Tags: c#, memory

In the project I made was a memory leak. I rewritten all the functions to fix some, but there was still one left:

The program has an object array of panels which grows everytime I put a new one in. When it reaches 400 panels, it deletes the oldest to free some memory.

What I don't understand is the following:

```
tempPanels = new Panel[panels.Length];
Array.Copy(panels, 1, tempPanels, 0, panels.Length - 1);//delete the oldest history log (the first of the array)
panels = null; //empty object array
panels = new Panel[tempPanels.Length + 1]; //set new length
tempPanels.CopyTo(panels, 0);//restore panels
```

When I use the code above the memory usage still keeps increasing... Can someone please explain why I have to dispose the panel first before I set panels to null?

```
tempPanels = new Panel[panels.Length];
Array.Copy(panels, 1, tempPanels, 0, panels.Length - 1);//delete the oldest history log (the first of the array)
panels[0].Dispose();
panels = null; //empty object array
panels = new Panel[tempPanels.Length + 1]; //set new length
tempPanels.CopyTo(panels, 0);//restore panels
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT @ Steve B:
The program makes a new panel: `panel currentPanel;`
When there is a new panel I declare currentPanel: `currentPanel = new Panel();`
After that I call this function: setCurrentPanelConfiguration:

```
public void setCurrentPanel()
{
  currentPanel.Name = "panel" + panels.Length;
  currentPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(485, 75);
  currentPanel.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
}
```

To fix a scroll bug I use a Panel HistoryPanel where I put the currentPanel:

```
HistoryPanel.Controls.Add(currentPanel);
```

Then I add all the controls: the username, current time and avatar.

To save the panel I add it to the array panels after I created a space as shown above:
 `panels[panels.Length-1] = currentPanel;`

I use an array because the history shows the newest one on top. To do that every time I have to shift all panels 80px down.

Comment: You can use the garbage collector to free memory: `GC.GetTotalMemory(true)`

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you have to call dispose on the panels first.
Otherwise, they will not bee freed.

Comment: If I use de garbage collector, where do I have to put it in the code and have I to create a destructor or something for the array?

Comment: Isn't manually calling the garbage collector a bad idea? Isn't the garbage collector supposed to detect free-able object itself and collect it when the program is idle?

Comment: @quispie: what are you trying to achieve exactly? I don't see any code where you insert the new panels in the control hierarchy. That said, instead of recreating arrays, why don't you use a collection, which size is dynamic (i.e. `List<Panel>` for the simplest)?

Comment: AFAIK the garbage collector shouldn't *ever* be called expicitly unless you *know* it needs to be invoked (handling unmanaged resources?). FYI if you make `panels` a collection (i.e. `List<>`) it would fit nicely in your code: `panels.RemoveAt(0);` and you're done.

Comment: @SteveB: I tried to use a List, but it didn't want to work so I made a array instead and works fine. A List would be better, I know, but I'm still learning and try to change it to a list in the future ;).

Comment: @Quispie: I suggest you to describe what is your requirement. I have the feeling you are going the wrong way. As I said, you create panels, without using them in the control hierarchy (or at least, you don't show us how). And arrays, in your case, may be very inefficiency if you reach a certain amount of panels.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because setting something to `null` does not dispose of it, it just dereferences it - the garbage collector isn't monitoring your assignments to check for your `null` references, it does it when it wants (all else being equal) or when explicitly told to do so.

In short, because `null` and memory management are different things.

Comment: Just imagine you have a box and you just take out whats inside. The box is still there. Thats what you are doing. Delete the entire node.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Grant Thomas said, why don't you use a `List<Panel>`, which is much easier to manage?

The code would read like this (assuming that `panels` was declared as `List<Panel>`):

```
Panel p = panels[0];
panels.RemoveAt(0);  // This removes the first element

p.Dispose(); // This disposes of the element
```

If you want to keep your code, it should read as follows:

```
tempPanels = new Panel[panels.Length];
Array.Copy(panels, 1, tempPanels, 0, panels.Length - 1);//delete the oldest history log (the first of the array)

// Dispose of every element in the array
for (int i = 0; i < panels.Length; i++)
    panels[i].Dispose();

// The following line is unneccessary, as the variable is re-assigned anyway
// panels = null; //empty object array

panels = new Panel[tempPanels.Length + 1]; //set new length
tempPanels.CopyTo(panels, 0);//restore panels
```

Comment: You are right! I was looking for a List because I was used to in Java, but it didn't want to work at all, so I made this solution and worked fine. The variable panels is declared like a normal array.